# How to insert criteria result object into database in hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am fetching data from database using criteria and the result is object. Now i want to save that object into database table so please suggest me how to do it.

Here is my **DAO** class

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
public List<Post> getPostList() throws Exception {
session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(Post.class);
    ProjectionList projList = Projections.projectionList();
    projList.add(Projections.sum("val"));
    projList.add(Projections.groupProperty("userId"));
    cr.setProjection(projList);
    List postList = cr.list();
    tx = session.getTransaction();
    session.beginTransaction();
    tx.commit();
    return postList;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply get your field form list and set it to your desired BO where your getter setters placed like

```
    Long sum=postList.get(0).getSum();
    YourBO b=new YourBO();
    b.setSum(sum);
    session.save(b);
```

now, you can insert your BO

Comment: and what is BO please explain?

Comment: @NadeemAhmed i updated my answer and you can add this code in your method where you want to save your object

Comment: Actually i want to automatically insert data after retrieving from criteria list...then what should i do please suggest me ?

Comment: Please write the whole method and where to call it ..please